# Cómo ingresar un scanner en un Arraylist para agregar, buscar, editar y borrar una posición y contenido en Java

Tags: java, arraylist, scanner

Tengo una duda de cómo puedo agregar un scanner a este código bajo la siguiente consigna:

Almacene en un ArrayList nombres de personas. Utilice un método que al digitar una posición muestre el dato que contiene. Luego utilice un método para agregar una posición. Luego un método que al digitar una posición elimine el dato que contiene y finalmente un método que al digitar una posición reemplace el dato que contiene por uno ingresado por el usuario.

Quisiera saber dónde está el error en el scanner al digitar la posicion me salte error

```
package poo.u3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ejercicio2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner elegirPosicion=new Scanner(System.in);

  ArrayList<String> nombres = new ArrayList<String>();

    nombres.add("Pedro");
    nombres.add("Laura");
    nombres.add("Marcelo");
    nombres.add("Pablo");


        System.out.println("Elija un numero de 1 a 4 para saber su nombre: ");
        int numeroSeleccionado = elegirPosicion.nextInt();
        int numeroPosicion = numeroSeleccionado-1;
        int i;



     if (nombres.indexOf(i)==numeroPosicion) {
                System.out.println("El numero elegido es "+ nombres.get(numeroPosicion));

            }
            else{
                System.out.println("La posicion "+numeroPosicion+" no esta en la lista.");
            } 
     }


}
```

Comment: Acostúmbrate en agregar en la pregunta el error que te sale.

Comment: es que ahí está mi error. No está bien eso. Por eso pregunto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La variable `i` nunca fue inicializada y al usarla en el método `indexOf`, el compilador dará un error de compilación, porque no tiene un valor inicial.

Como el parámetro del método `indexOf` recibe el elemento a buscar, podemos hacer esto:

```java
int i = numeroPosicion;
if (nombres.indexOf(nombres.get(i)) == numeroPosicion) 
    System.out.println("El numero elegido es "+ nombres.get(numeroPosicion));
  else
    System.out.println("La posicion "+numeroPosicion+" no esta en la lista.");
```

No es necesario usar el método `indexOf`, debido a que, el método [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) lanza la excepción [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) cuando el índice está fuera de rango.

Código java:

```java
System.out.println("Elija un numero de 1 a 4 para saber su nombre: ");
int numeroSeleccionado = elegirPosicion.nextInt() - 1;
try
{
    System.out.println("El nombre elegido es "+ nombres.get(numeroSeleccionado));
}
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
{
    System.out.println("La posicion "+numeroSeleccionado+" no esta en la lista.");
}
```

Si no quieres usar el `try-catch` puedes verificar si el índice está fuera de rango usando el método `size()` de la clase `ArrayList`.

```java
System.out.println("Elija un numero de 1 a 4 para saber su nombre: ");
int numeroSeleccionado = elegirPosicion.nextInt() - 1;

if(numeroSeleccionado >= 0 && numeroSeleccionado < nombres.size())
    System.out.println("El nombre elegido es "+ nombres.get(numeroSeleccionado));
else
    System.out.println("La posicion "+numeroSeleccionado+" no esta en la lista.");
```